# Title of a book about an (annual?) competition between different races

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to identify the title of a novel, possibly part of a series of novels which contains an annual(?) competition between various races such as snake people, horse people and humans as well as (maybe) others. It might not be specifically annual but I do know that it's a big event that is held *regularly*. I'm fairly sure it was a YA fantasy book with elements of sci fi.

- Part one of the competition is basically arena fighting. It's a 1 vs. 1 scenario with the winner progressing onto the next round.
- A female main character learns how to fight from one of the snake people using a fighting style called something like *"capoeira"*.
- Part two of the competition is assorted skills such as archery, cooking and tech.
- The writing POV switches every (few) chapter(s) between 2 main characters (guy/girl).

---

It's not "[Girl in the Arena](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6449916-girl-in-the-arena)"

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Please try to add anything that may help identification. Review this [**checklist**](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337). When did you read it?  What language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Comment: I'm at a loss who'd vote to close this as too broad. It seems to contain a number of elements that would make it immediately identifiable.

Comment: :) Capoeira is a real-life martial art practiced in Brazil. Interesting. So the female main character was human?

Comment: yes she was. the description of the fighting style in the book is quite similar to the real life "capoeira", but i'm not sure if they're exactly the same or even if it's spelled the same.

Comment: When did you read this? And was it in English? Did it seem to be our Earth?

Comment: i think i read this 1-2 years ago. it was in english, and it bore resemblance to our earth geographically, but in regards to society/tech/etc. not really.